# Force render of ImageCanvas layer in OL3?

Tags: javascript, openlayers-3

I have an image layer that uses an ***ImageCanvas*** source.
I need to dynamically change things on that canvas surface and have them change on the layer, but unless I drastically change the extent, say by zooming, the layer ignores any changes I've made to the canvas.

Is there any way to force a given layer to render? I've tried ***map.render()***, which works in some contexts, but not others

```
MapScholar.prototype.CreateCanvasLayer = function()                     
{        
    this.canvasLayer = new ol.layer.Image( {                                    
        source: new ol.source.ImageCanvas( {                                
            canvasFunction: function(extent, res, pixelRatio, size, proj) { 
                if (!this.canvas)                                       
                    this.canvas=document.createElement('canvas');       
                this.canvas.setAttribute('width', size[0]);             
                this.canvas.setAttribute('height', size[1]);            
                return this.canvas;                                     
                } 
            })
        });
    map.addLayer(this.canvasLayer);                                         
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can indicate that something has changed on a source by calling `changed` on that source. In your case:

```js
this.canvasLayer.getSource().changed();
```

Calling `changed` basically invalidates the current canvas in the `ImageCanvas` source and triggers a `change` event, which will result in a re-render of the map.

Note that the `changed` function is not marked as "stable", so it may change in the future. You have to uncheck the "Stable Only" checkbox in the API doc to see that function. Here's a direct link: http://openlayers.org/en/master/apidoc/ol.Observable.html?unstable=true.

EDIT: the `changed` function is name `dispatchChangeEvent` in the v3.0.0 version. It is `changed` in the master branch.

Comment: I added `this.canvasLayer.getSource().dispatchChangeEvent()`, using the ol-debug.js version of the release, and it hides the layer when called.

Comment: Sorry to say it doesn't. It **hides** the layer, as opposed to show it. Any other ideas?

Comment: I'd have to see this in an example.

Comment: but maybe it needs the most recent build. Hate to ask a stupid question, but is there a link to that anywhere?

Comment: OK. I'm workong on code subset and will post it as a new issue,